# ¿Juan y María se ayudan el uno al otro, el uno a la otra o la una al otro?

Tags: gramática

Aparentemente [algunos gramáticos aceptan](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/uno-a-otro-el-uno-al-otro-articulo/) las dos primeras posibilidades:

> (a) Juan y María se ayudan el uno al otro.
>
> (b) Juan y María se ayudan el uno a la otra.

¿Entonces también la tercera, *la una al otro*, es aceptada?

¿Pero alguien dice «se ayudan el uno a la otra»? ¿No significaría eso solamente que Juan (el uno) ayuda a María (la otra)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si *Juan y María se ayudan el uno a la otra* está aceptada, entonces los mismos gramáticos deberían aceptar igualmente *María y Juan se ayudan la una al otro*, pero –y esto en opinión de una nativa, ya que no he sido capaz de encontrar referencias al respecto–, **es preferible respetar el orden de los términos**. Es decir:

> Juan y María se ayudan el uno a la otra — preferible
>
> Juan y María se ayudan la una al otro — evitable
>
> María y Juan se ayudan la una al otro — preferible
>
> María y Juan se ayudan el uno a la otra — evitable

Sin embargo, debe tenerse en cuenta que *el uno al otro* es tan común que ya se ha convertido en una frase hecha, una locución con el significado de *recíprocamente*. Las expresiones *el uno a la otra* y *la una al otro* pueden sonar raras a algunos hispanohablantes (aunque aquí tienen mucho que ver las diferencias regionales), por lo que [la RAE recomienda](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5) evitarlas.

Finalmente, si se usa la construcción *el uno a la otra/la una al otro* se genera una cierta incongruencia. Por una parte, se interpretaría que la ayuda es mutua por el uso del "se": el "se" en "se ayudan" es un "se recíproco", es decir que el mero uso de tal partícula ya señala reciprocidad. Además, el verbo está en plural, con lo que deben de ser (al menos) dos los que ayudan. Pero por otra parte, expresiones como *el uno a la otra/la una al otro* se oyen con tan poca frecuencia que pierden su carácter de frase hecha, y parecen implicar que la ayuda es unidireccional, lo cual es contradictorio con el uso del "se" y la conjugación del verbo. Todo ello es cuanto menos confuso, por lo que, nuevamente, se recomienda utilizar la expresión estándar "el uno al otro".

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta (+1), me plantea algunas dudas. Por un lado, en los ejemplos de la RAE no es especifica un orden entre ambos sujetos, lo que puede dar más ambigüedad al género. Por otro, usar géneros distintos parece indicar que la ayuda va en un solo sentido (uno a la otra -> Juan es quien ayuda a María). Yo creo que evitaría usar construcciones con género y diría *Juan y María se ayudan entre sí*.

Comment: Sé que no lo especifica, por eso añadí la aclaración "y esto en opinión de una nativa, ya que no he sido capaz de encontrar referencias al respecto". No creo que exista posibilidad de equivocación por el uso del "se", aunque la poca frecuencia del uso el uno a la otra/la una al otro podría llevar a confusión. Ya he modificado mi respuesta para dejarlo más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres ahorrarte el problema de géneros, puedes usar *mutuamente*:

> X e Y se ayudan *mutuamente*.

Nótese que la partícula *se* juega un rol bastante importante. Si *se* se elimina, tendremos:

> X e Y ayudan *mutuamente*,

esto implica que ambos proveen ayuda al mismo tiempo, pero no que sea recíproca como Yay dijo.

Comment: He ahí la solución perfecta.